# how to replace one line with two lines in txt file

Tags: powershell

I want some .cs model file to append annotation. If script finds specific property it will put above that property annotation.

Here is the script:

```
$annotation = "[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]"
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.cs | % {
(Get-Content $_.FullName) | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match "StartDateTime") {
        $_ -replace $_ , "`n`t`t$annotation`n$_" 
    }
  } | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

It works with replacing, but at the end I get a blank file with only two lines (annotation and custom property). I realize that the last pipeline Set-Content $_.FullName is messed up.
If I remove Set-Content, nothing happens with my file (it's not updated)?

Comment: You only put the matched line in the pipeline. Add an else: else { $_ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work better for you:

```
$filePath = '<YOUR PATH HERE>'
$annotation = "[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]"
Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Filter *.cs | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object { 
        # test all strings in $file
        if ($_ -match "StartDateTime") {
            # emit the annotation followed by the string itself
            "`r`n`t`t$annotation`r`n" + $_
        }
        else { 
            # just output the line as-is
            $_
        }
    }  | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
}
```

Within the `Foreach-Object` I'm capturing the `$_.FullName` for later use and also to not confuse it with the `$_` you use later on as line in the file.
Then, if the line does match the `if`, output the replaced line, but if it does not (in the `else`) you should output the line unchanged.
Then, the `Set-Content` always outputs each line, replaced or not.

Since you actually are not replacing anything inside the string, but rather prefixing it with an annotation, this can be simplified a bit like so:

```
$annotation = "[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]"
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Filter *.cs | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object { 
        # test all strings in $file
        if ($_ -match "StartDateTime") {
            # emit the annotation
            "`r`n`t`t$annotation"
        }
        # output the line as-is
        $_
    }  | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that I missed the else part. Thanks